# How to set visible length for type tinyint,smallint while alter column using phinx migration in cakephp3?

Tags: mysql, database-migration, cakephp-3.x, phinx

I tried the following code to migrate a field "exp" to datatype tinyint(2), i want to make visible-length 2 with datatype tinyint.

```
$table->changeColumn('exp', 'integer', [
            'limit' =>  MysqlAdapter::INT_TINY,
//is there any option to set visible length 2, by default it is taking length 4
//I tried 'length'=>4, but it overrides 'limit' and datatype becomes int(4)
            'null' => false,
            'default' => '0'
        ]);
```

[I want alter the column with this type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaw7g.png)

Comment: please do not down vote, i went through the docs provided by phinx, but did not find any answer to this query.

Comment: Note: Without `ZEROFILL` there is no difference between `TINYINT(2)` and `TYNYINT(4)`.

Comment: I understand you point @PaulSpiegel you are right but, since the ZEROFILL is not provided in the new table structure i have not mentioned it.I checked the phinx docs, there is no option for ZEROFILL as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try plain query:

```
$this->execute('ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD COLUMN `exp` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0');
```